# how to serach text in text box along button after or before text search in wpf

Tags: wpf

txt_result.Focus();
            int index1 = txt_result.Text.Substring(txt_result.SelectionStart + txt_result.SelectionLength).ToUpper().IndexOf(txt_serach.Text.ToUpper());
            if (index1 == -1)
                txt_result.Select(0, 0);
            else
                txt_result.Select(index1 + txt_result.SelectionStart + txt_result.SelectionLength, txt_serach.Text.Length);
            txt_serach.Focus();

Comment: can you add some description what u want to achieve

Comment: http://up.iranblog.com/uploads/74070.png for example